# Highlight rows based pf column criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Im trying to write a VBA script to compare two = rows and have the spreadsheet highlight the duplicate rows only if certain criteria is met, such as (Value of row, column a = Value of row-1, column) AND Value of row, column b > Value of row-1, column b) Then entirerow of the greater value in column b.font.color = vbRed.

Here is a section of the table I'm running...

[Table Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9s6s.jpg)

Here is the code I am using...

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim i As Long, R As Long
'Dim DeviceName As Range, SerialNumber As Range, LastContact As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

R = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Set DeviceName = Columns(2)
'Set SerialNumber = Columns(3)
'Set LastContact = Columns(7)

For i = R To 2 Step -1

'If Cells(i, "F").Value > Cells(i - 1, "F").Value Then
'Code above doesn't work

If Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then

    'If Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value And Cells(i, 5).Value > Cells(i - 1, 5).Value Then
    'Code above doesn't work

    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I can get the duplicates to highlight, but when I try to introduce the greater than check, the system gets janky.

[image]

Comment: Your code contradicts itself and the narrative in terms of what columns are to be used for the conditions. Perhaps it would be best to simply spell it out word-for-word what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

try a conditional formatting rule.

```
With worksheets("sheet1").usedrange.offset(1, 0).entirerow
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and($a2=$a1, $b2=$b1, $f2>$f1)")
        .font.Color = vbRed
    End With
End With
```